# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 "_r8_huge_"

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I have a `.f90` file which I compile with:

```
gfortran -c -o objs/mod_interp.o ../extern/mod_interp.f90 -g -fPIC -Imods -I../header_files -Jmods
```

The rest of the objects are compiled from F77 files, and then everything is linked with:

```
gfortran -o WIM2d.exec objs/p_WIM2d.o objs/mod_WIM2d_run.o objs/mod_interp.o objs/mod_file_utils.o objs/mod_gridinfo.o objs/mod_wim_init.o objs/mod_common_wim.o objs/mod_wim_prams.o objs/RTparam_outer.o objs/RTparam_fast.o objs/RTparam_hardcoded_v2.o objs/mod_RTparam_utilities.o objs/mod_adv_atten.o objs/mod_advect.o objs/mod_wavesice.o -g -fPIC -Imods -I../header_files
```

However I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_r8_huge_", referenced from:
      ___mod_interp_MOD_pwl_interp_2d in mod_interp.o
  "_r8vec_bracket5_", referenced from:
      ___mod_interp_MOD_pwl_interp_2d in mod_interp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I am working on a mac with OSX 10.10.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I changed the title. It is unlikely the error is caused by the fact it is Fortran 77 or 90. Always use tag [tag:fortran]. Find in your code any occurrences of  `r8_huge` and `r8vec_bracket5`. It should be in `mod_interp.f90`. Show the relevant code!

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for the tip. It seems the two "symbols" (a parameter and a function) were in another file which I didn't realise went along with the subroutine in mod_interp.f90. I thought they were intrinsic to f90 or something like that, but after copying the 2 things into my module, it compiled fine.